# How to apply linear independence on the infinitesimals?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Let $F(x,y,z): \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}dz$.

If $x,y,z$ are linear independent, how to use the defination of the linear independent to proof $\nexists\left(a,b,c\right) \neq \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right): dF = adx+bdy+cdz$.

Linear independence is defined on vectors. $dx,dy,dz$ , which are infintesimals, are scalars. Is there any method for appling the defination of the linear independence on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, linear independence is defined in every vector space (or more general module). Here, you are looking at the tangent space which is spanned by the partial derivatives. Since they form a basis of the tangent space, you know that every vector in the tangent space, e.g. $dF$, admits a unique representation as linear combination in the basis. Consequently, $dx, dy, dz$ is the only possibility.

Comment: I am not familiar with the tangent space. Are there any recommended books for studying?

Comment: This isn’t really necessary for your purposes. You can just take as definition that it is the vector space spanned by the partial derivatives. But you will find more information in every basic book on differential geometry or algebraic geometry (i recommend looking at differential geometry first).

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!